# Sturctured Query Language

Tags: sql

```
create table customer(
    custno number(10) constraint foo primary key,
    custname character(15),
    city character(15),
    phone number(10));

create table invoice(
    invo number(10) constraint inv primary key,
    invdate date(10),
    constarint c references customer(custno));
```

I cannot able to create the second table and am having doubt of the data type date and If I neglected that attribute(invdate) still I cannot able to create the second table.Reason please.

Comment: At least `,constarint` is wrong. A field custno_fk seems to be gone missing.

Comment: detailed explanation?

Comment: It looks like a misspelling of "constraint". `invdate date, custno number(10) references customer(custno)`. (Constraint+name optional, not given here.) _People seem to be down-voting because the question is just about syntax. Do not mind._

Comment: @SindhujaSelvaraj Does it give you any errors?

Comment: yes first it was showing error but now got rectified! thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
create table customer
  ( custno    int constraint foo primary key
   ,custname  character(15)
   ,city      character(15)
   ,phone    int
  )
  go
create table invoice
  (  invo int constraint inv primary key
   constraint ck references customer(custno)
   ,invdate date
  )
```